# In inspect mode text showing &nbsp for space in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, character-encoding

I have a two-span element in my one of a project which rendered on two different pages, in which when I inspect it the first span shows:

[image]

where the second span element looks like **which is the main problem**:

[image]

In both cases on-page it's showing the same output.

some important points:

- I am fetching this value from .csv file
- For both span .csv file are
  different
- Checked in Microsoft Edge its working fine not working in chrome

What could be the problem or how I can determine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonbreaking space might be the issue, especially if it's coming from a .csv file.
I had this problem with an API fetch, just had to use the [replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to get a clean text.

If you inspect this sentence, notice the nonbreaking spaces ! (might be a fail if stackoverflow patched this kind of behaviors)

Comment: but in CSV  its proper like `"First Name"` and it works for other pages only this page

Comment: Nonbreaking space are invisible, check my sentence above, there is 3 of them, but you can't tell visually.
Sometimes it comes from a copy paste... Try to re write your sentence in the .csv and try again!

Tips : the macOS shortcut for this is "alt + space".

Comment: let me check this looks like a problem but the code is in production, how I can test it on browser

Comment: Try copy pasting in a div the "first page" text who seems to bug, and inspect it with your chrome tool or whatever inspector.

Comment: Thank it resolved but how to determine word contains space or &nbsp? as csv clearly show space?